# Outputting the results of a nested for loop to a file in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have been attempting to create a file out of my loop in bash , I was successful in generating the file with the following code

```
for ((i = 0; i <= 5; i++)); do
  for ((j = i; j <= 5; j++)); do
    echo -e "$i $j" >> numbers.txt
  done 
done
```

however I want my results to be out in the following fashion

```
 01

 02

 03
```

etc.

But the result I am getting is similar to this

```
0 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 1 1 1 2 1 3 1 4 1 5 2 2 2 3 2 4 2 5 3 3 3 4 3 5
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: If you don't want the space between the two digits, then you can just omit it. Or - better - use `printf` for formatted output `printf '%d%d\n' "$i" "$j"`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply .. i want the ouputs to be on a new line, meaning each pair generated. so the n pair is on a line and the n+1 pair on a new line and so on

Comment: @heemayl my text was formatted right :P i am not getting the results on a new line am getting all of them on the same line

Comment: Are you sure? Each should be on its own line unless you used `echo -n`. What platform are you on?

Comment: If you're really getting everything on the same line, you didn't run the code you showed us.

Comment: You don't need C-style for loops here:  `for i in {0..5}; do for j in {1..5}; do printf "%d%d\n\n" "$i" "$j"; done; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` *has* C-style for loops, but stylistically they're a little odd to use when you don't have to.  And if you really do absolutely *have* to, [you *might* be using the wrong language](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943).  (For this use case shell is fine, of course.)

A much more shell-like way to do this (in my opinion) is:

```
for i in {0..5}; do for j in $(seq "$i" 5); do echo "$i$j"; done; done
```

Here is another approach:

```
(set {0..5}; for i; do for j; do [ "$i" -le "$j" ] && echo "$i$j"; done; done)
```

I write these as one-liners suitable for an interactive shell, but they work equally well in structured form (which would usually be preferable in a script):

```
set {0..5}
for i; do
  for j; do
    [ "$i" -le "$j" ] &&
      printf '%d%d\n' "$i" "$j"
  done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ((i = 0; i <= 5; i++)); do
  for ((j = i; j <= 5; j++)); do
    echo -e "${i}${j}\n" >> numbers.txt
  done 
done
```

Should do the trick. I removed the space, I prefer using `{}`'s around my variables and `\n` puts in new line.

Comment: Adding `\n` adds an empty line, since `echo` already outputs a newline character at the end.

Comment: Yes, which is what they want according to the desired result specified.